# NSOperationQueue with UIImage causes memory warning

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm using NSOperationQueue to upload photos to a distant web-server, but when uploading more than 10 photos, memory warning appears and RAM used exceeds 150 Mo. Worst, once the photo picker has disappeared, the RAM is not deallocated... Here's the code used:

```swift
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in
            for i in 0..<self.assets.count {
                let operation: SWSingleUploadOperation = SWUploadManager.sharedManager.operationForPhoto(self.assets[i].editedAsset!,
                    progress: { (progress: Float) -> Void in
                        self.updateCellForOperationIndex(i,
                            withState: .Uploading,
                            andProgress: progress)
                    },
                    completion: { (response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if response?.statusCode == 200 && error == nil {
                            self.updateCellForOperationIndex(i,
                                withState: .Success,
                                andProgress: 1.0)
                        }
                        else {
                            self.updateCellForOperationIndex(i,
                                withState: .Fail,
                                andProgress: 0.0)
                        }
                })
                operation.delegate = self
                self.cellStates[NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)] = (state: .Uploading, progress: nil)
                self.uploadOperations.append(operation)
                self.uploadQueue?.addOperation(operation)
            }
```

Here's the `operationForPhoto` method used below:

```swift
let photoData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.8)!
return SWSingleUploadOperation(requestParameters: (uploadID: self.uploadParameters!.uploadID, data: photoData),
                progressHandler: pProgress,
                completionHandler: pCompletion)
```

And here's my NSOperation subclass content:

```swift
var delegate: SingleUploadOperationDelegate?

var requestParameters: (uploadID: String, data: NSData)?
var progressHandler: ((progress: Float) -> Void)?
var completionHandler: ((response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void)?

weak var request: Alamofire.Request?

init(requestParameters: (sweebiId: String, data: NSData),
    progressHandler: ((progress: Float) -> Void)?,
    completionHandler: ((response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void)?) {
        self.requestParameters = requestParameters
        self.progressHandler = progressHandler
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        super.init()
}

override func main() {
    self.delegate?.uploadOperationDidStart(self)

    self.request = Alamofire.upload(Router.AddImageToSweebi(sweebiId: self.requestParameters!.uploadID),
        data: self.requestParameters!.data)
    .validate()
    .progress { (bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) -> Void in
        self.progressHandler?(progress: Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
    }
    .response(completionHandler: { (request: NSURLRequest?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.requestParameters = nil
        self.progressHandler = nil
        self.completionHandler?(response: response, error: error)
        self.completeOperation()
    })
}

override func cancel() {
    self.request?.cancel()
    self.delegate?.uploadOperationDidCancel(self)
    super.cancel()
}
```

Do you have any idea of why such RAM is used, and how to avoid this and deallocate it once the photo picker has been dismissed?

Comment: IMHO, you should add Alamofire tag in your question.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the problem, but I'd start by looking at a possible retain cycle with your operation and its delegate. You have `operation.delegate = self`, but `operation` is itself stored in `self.uploadOperations`. On completion of the operation, you should set `operation.delegate = nil` and remove the operation from the `uploadOperations` collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a good start but unfortunately I just set delegate to nil in the completion block and removed all operations once done before dismissing the photo picker, and the ram used is still not deallocated...

Comment: After a batch of tests, this is relative to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` but I can't see any other way to proceed to convert my image to NSData...